# What would cause gcc to not recognize a "bool" anymore?

Tags: linux, gcc, boolean

I had written plenty of code using Booleans and complied and built with no problem. Then the compiler and even the editor no longer recognizes "bool".  A fix I did was to "`#include <stdbool.h>`" to recognize the Booleans.

But I'd like to know what could possibly cause this problem?

Comment: Not including `stdbool.h` in C?

Comment: didn't have to do that until recently

Comment: In C, the only other way you get there with gcc is to `#define bool`, e.g. `typedef enum {FALSE = 0, TRUE = !FALSE} bool;` (and ensure `TRUE` and `FALSE` are defined). I've never had it work without `stdbool.h` (strange) Did you have a header that pulled in a custom bool maybe? What changed? Did you update versions, etc?

Comment: This is not a problem, it is expected. `bool` is defined in `stdbool.h`

Comment: I think your question needs a language reference. C? C++? Fortran? I believe GCC can even build Ada code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C11, the type `bool` is only defined if the standard header stdbool.h is included. Otherwise, the type has to be referred to as `_Bool`. This was the result of the complete absence of a boolean type in earlier revisions of the standard, and the focus on backwards compatibility in the evolution of said standard.

In C++, the `bool` type is available without including any header, just like `int`.

Your question is about GCC, not about the C standard, but while GCC does take some obscure liberties with the C standard if you do not use commandline options such as `-std=c11 -pedantic` to make it a standard-compliant compiler, in the case of the type `bool`, it follows the C standard and abstains from defining it.

It is likely that you were compiling code as C++ previously and are now compiling it as C. Another possibility is that you were including an application header that was including stdbool.h or that provided its own definition of `bool`, and that you ceased to include this header.

(It would even be possible to imagine in theory that the header in question was a system header that was including stdbool.h previously and ceased to when you upgraded your compilation platform. In principle, there is no guarantee about which system header may include what other system headers. In practice, though, since the only purpose of stdbool.h is to preserve compatibility with old code that does not include it, stdbool.h would never be included by another system header.)